# Exclude records from query where some columns are all not equal to a value

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am relatively new to ACCESS 2010 and to SQL. Having a bit of trouble figuring this one out.

I have a a query that returns a result from a table. I want to exclude any records where the values in columns A1-A4 all equal zero.

ex:

```
+----+----------+----+----+----+----+
| ID | CustName | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
+----+----------+----+----+----+----+
|  1 | Ben      |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
|  2 | Tom      |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  3 | Jerry    |  0 |  0 |  2 |  0 |
|  4 | Steve    |  0 |  3 |  0 |  0 |
|  5 | Dave     |  4 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
|  6 | Mike     |  0 |  0 |  2 |  1 |
|  7 | Sheila   |  0 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
|  8 | Jonesy   |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
+----+----------+----+----+----+----+
```

Using the table above as the source for the query, the only record I want to be excluded should be the very first record.

The SQL I am using for this query is

```
SELECT Test.CustName, Test.A1, Test.A2, Test.A3, Test.A4
FROM Test
WHERE (((Test.A1)<>0) AND ((Test.A2)<>0) AND ((Test.A3)<>0) AND ((Test.A4)<>0));
```

This SQL will only return records where all columns from A1-A4 are NOT equal to zero and only returns the final record. It should return record 2 - 7.

Comment: Can A1 thru A4 contain Null?  If so, should Null be treated the same as zero?

Comment: In the real life scenario that this question is based on I had already converted all NULL values to zero because this was causing problems with other queries. Is there a way of treating NULL values as ZERO?

Comment: Thanks to everyone that replied, your help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You want `OR`, not `AND`:

```
SELECT Test.CustName, Test.A1, Test.A2, Test.A3, Test.A4
FROM Test
WHERE (((Test.A1)<>0) OR ((Test.A2)<>0) OR ((Test.A3)<>0) OR ((Test.A4)<>0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`

```
SELECT t.CustName, t.A1, t.A2, t.A3, t.A4
FROM Test t
WHERE (((t.A1)!=0) 
OR ((t.A2)!=0)
OR ((t.A3)!=0) 
OR ((t.A4)!=0));
```

Answer (score 0):

If those values are not negative you can also do

```
where A1+A2+A3+A3 > 0
```